# Why can't I log things in Angular guard?

Tags: angular, routes

I have a Route protected by a Guard which doesn't work. And when I try to console.log for debugging nothing happens. What am I missing?

Here's my app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ForetagsprofilComponent } from 
import { UserHasJwtToken } from './guards/user-has-jwt-token.guard';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SearchForetagsprofilComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'redigera',
    component: ForetagsprofilComponent,
    canActivate: [UserHasJwtToken]
  }
```

And here's my guard user-has-jwt-token.guard.ts:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AfUserService } from '../services/af-user-service';
import { AfUserInfo } from '../model/af-user-info';

@Injectable()
export class UserHasJwtToken implements CanActivate, OnInit {

  private _afUserInfo = new AfUserInfo();
  constructor(private afUserService: AfUserService, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.afUserService.getUserInfo().subscribe(response => {
      this._afUserInfo = response;
    });

    console.log('Customernumber: ' + this.afUserService.getUserInfo());
  }
```

Comment: To my knowledge guards aren't components so they don't make use of the OnInit lifecycle hook so it won't run - so if you want to log do it in the canActivate() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `canActivate` method which needs to return a boolean or observable. In your case, like this:

```
canActivate() {
  console.log('Checking if there is user info');
  // I am not subscribing here. I am just returning the observable.
  // Router will subscribe to it on each call.
  return this.afUserService.getUserInfo()
  .pipe(
     // We do, however, wanna log the response 
     tap(response => console.log('Got response:', response);
     // Also, we wanna return a boolean. E.g if there's a property `isLoggedIn`on the response.
     // if we return true, the routing happens. if we return false, the router blocks the route.
     map(response => response.isLoggedIn),
  );
```

`canActivate` method is part of the **CanActivate** interface you imported from Angular and tried to implement. Maybe your IDE (e.g. VS Code) warned you that this method is missing - you should check those kinds of errors, they'd point out the problem immediately to you. You can run things like `ng lint` to check for these kinds of issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
this.afUserService.getUserInfo().subscribe(response => {
      this._afUserInfo = response;
    });

    console.log('Customernumber: ' + this.afUserService.getUserInfo());
}
```

This will work fine!